# How to fetch data of My own Google Analytics Account using Service account keys?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I need to get all My Analytics data in My Front-end . It's need to Be Handle All in Front-end using JavaScript .. 
For  Python & PHP Library is Available But I want to  handle All in Front-end As It's Admin Side of Our App & want some fast Processing..

Any Suggestion or Example How Can I achieve that using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Finally Got the Solution :
As you Need  TO user Your Service Account Key (.Json File) And Need To use Google Analytics Embedded API . & you can use Any chart Library in THis..
Find Below Link for More Information

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/

[https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/)

Answer (score 1):

For starters you cant get **ALL** of your Google Analytics data.  The api limits the number of dimensions and metrics you can request at a time.  There is no primary key so once you select out that data there will be no way to match that data with a second request.

You can use a service account to extract the data using PHP or python and then display it using JavaScript.  I am sure someone has gotten a service account working with JavaScript but for security reasons this is not something I would personally attempt.